# Debugging a PHP file called by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, debugging, upload, uploadify

I'm using uploadify (a jQuery uploading) script, which has basically a PHP file at the backend. I want to do some kind of debugging of PHP code, (for example see what kind of errors I get in the PHP file (when it's called by jQuery), but I don't know how I can print the errors. For example the original PHP file is:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_GET['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}   
?>
```

Now for example I add a line before move_uploaded_file() in the above code.

```
die("die befor moving file");
```

When this PHP file is called by the script, it won't go to the next line but it wont print the message either. How can I print the error message? If it can't be done this way, can I display some javascript alert message. The idea is to know where the error in the PHP file is. Thanks.

Here's the front end uploading page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
        'folder': 'files',
        'multi': false,
        'displayData': 'speed'
    });

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset style="border: 1px solid #CDCDCD; padding: 8px; ">
        <legend><strong>Uploadify Sample</strong></legend>
        <h2>Single File Upload</h2>
        <p>Display speed</p>
        <div id="fileUpload">You have a problem with your javascript</div>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
   ...
   'onComplete': function(a, b, c, data, e){
       alert(data);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

if your using apache server get httpd.conf file and search for `ErrorLog` log location and open the log file you will have proper error message to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [FirePHP](http://reference.developercompanion.com/#/Tools/FirePHPCompanion/Introduction/) library + Firefox extension to print error messages in PHP that are visible in your browser.

Comment: It would be an good try, but uploadfy dont show any messages from Firephp...The messages just dont show

Answer (score 0):

The Upload process is actually done by a flash "uploadify/uploader.swf" some flash uploader came with a debug mode so you can see the response from PHP.

Worst case you can tell PHP to write some debug line into a external log file with [put_file_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

[EDIT:] According this page http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/2085/built-in-debug/p1 Uploadify doesn't come with a debug mode. So you are better writing in a log file with file_put_contents
Also this flash works like a normal HTML form (except that flash can retrieve a percentage of uploading), so you can create a simple HTML form thant send a file through  your PHP such as:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Upload file</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="yourFile.php">
       <input type="file" name="Filedata" />
       <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```