# Uploadify: Write complete but there are no files uploaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, upload, uploadify

I want upload images with uploadify v.3.1 (flash). I click on select files, choose a file, the file is uploaded but in the end I get the error message:

`haus2.jpg (256KB) - HTTP Error (401)`

`php.ini` settings:

```
memory_limit: 256M
upload_max_filesize: 40M
post_max_size: 8M
```

My php file where I use uploadify:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function() {
            $('#image_upload1').uploadify({
                'swf'            : '/project/swf/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader'       : '/project/includes/uploadify.php',
                'cancelImg'      : '/project/images/static/uploadify-cancel.png',
                'folder'         : '/project/images/uploaded/<?php echo $_SESSION['newCreatedID']; ?>',
                'multi'          : true,
                'auto'           : true,
                'removeCompleted': false,
                'queueSizeLimit' : 10,
                'simUploadLimit' : 10,
                'fileExt'        : '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.gif',
                'fileDesc'       : 'JPG Image Files (*.jpg); JPEG Image Files (*.jpeg); PNG Image Files (*.png), GIF (*.gif)',
                'onUploadError'  : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                    alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
                },
                'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response) {
                    alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was successfully uploaded with a response of ' + response + ':' + data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="step2_do.php" name="newEntry" id="newEntry" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="image_upload1" name="image_upload1" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit" id="submit-btn" class="inputform" />
</form>
```

There is no error thrown.

But there is no error. In Firebug there is never an error shown. The uploaded folder has 777 rights and I removed the proposed `.htaccess` in there.

`uploadify.php`:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0777, true);
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
}
```

I cannot find any error. What are my possibilites to debug?

I don't get any errors with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

**Edit:**

Now I completely forgot about a htaccess needing a password for accessing the site. Now fileupload is writing complete but there is no folder/files on the server. I implemented `onUploadSuccess` which brings me the following error message:

```
The file haus.jpg was successfully uploaded with a response of true:<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mkdir() [<a href='function.mkdir'>function.mkdir</a>]: File exists in <b>/home/myuser/www/home/project/includes/uploadify.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
/haus.jpg
```

The main problem was that I mixed up the old API of uploadify with the new one. For debugging I used:

```
$request = implode(";", $_REQUEST);
file_put_contents('uploadify.txt', chr(10) . ": request" . $request, FILE_APPEND);
```

My final initialization looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $('#image_upload1').uploadify({
            'swf'            : '/project/swf/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader'       : '/project/includes/uploadify.php',
            'formData'       : {'folder' : '/project/images/uploaded/<?php echo $_SESSION['newCreatedID']; ?>'},
            'multi'          : true,
            'auto'           : true,
            'removeCompleted': false,
            'queueSizeLimit' : 10,
            'simUploadLimit' : 10,
            'fileTypeExt'        : '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.gif',
            'fileTypeDesc'       : 'JPG Image Files (*.jpg); JPEG Image Files (*.jpeg); PNG Image Files (*.png), GIF (*.gif)',
            'onUploadError'  : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
            },
            'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response) {
                alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was successfully uploaded with a response of ' + response + ':' + data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`formData` should be used ...

Comment: not sure, but check the [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown)  of folder `/project/images/uploaded/`

Comment: What web server are you using?  Apache?  Does the apache user (possibly www-data) have rights to /projects/images/uploaded?

Comment: @SamMirrado: I can successfully create a folder with this script: `$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/project/images/uploaded/84' . '/'; echo $targetPath; echo mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0750, true);`

Comment: So nothing is getting written, even to your tempFile?

Comment: @SamMirrado: How can I look into `$tempFile`?

Comment: Sorry, meant to ask if the data is valid in $_FILES['Filedata'].  Is $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] > ''?  Does move_uploaded_file() return True or False?

Comment: @SamMirrado: So I put an echo directly into `uploadify.php`? I think then I'll not see any results or? See my edited question at the end.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578451/debugging-a-php-file-called-by-jquery

Comment: @SamMirrado: I made this `file_put_contents('uploadify.txt', chr(10) . ": path" . $targetPath, FILE_APPEND);` but here I see that only `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` has been taken. Why is `$_REQUEST['folder']` empty? The files were uploaded in the root folder ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

401 suggests that the user needs to be authenticated before uploading.

You might try sending back your $.cookie('sessionid') in the parameter list, to make sure it knows what session is doing the upload.

Comment: this is not necessarily a problem of authetification. The 401 error can appear when the user does not have sufficient rights owner to access folder

Comment: @testing Sam was right if it was htaccess, to give credit where it's due